# Error: "expected command in 'choose-exit'" evacuation simulation

Tags: simulation, netlogo, cellular-automata

I'm getting an error message saying `expected command in 'choose-exit'` and the issue seems to be in the line "choose-exit patch-here" within the "initialize-passengers" procedure. I've checked the code and everything seems correct, so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

```
breed [  passengers    passenger]
breed [  fire-spots  a-fire-spot]
breed [ smoke-spots a-smoke-spot]

globals [        exit1            ;;   pID
                 exit2            ;;   pID
                 exits-list       ;; [ pID ... ]
                 passenger_count  ;;   integer
  
]

passengers-own [ in-seat?         ;; boolean
                 safe?            ;; boolean
                 dead?            ;; boolean
                 panic?           ;; boolean
                 current-heading  ;; turtleHDG
                 target-exit      ;;   pID
                 my-exits-list    ;; [ pID ... ]
                 item?            ;; boolean
]

patches-own [    accessible?      ;; boolean
                 fire?            ;; boolean
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; FUNZIONI SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to setup
   
   __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
     ;;;;;; DEBUG
            type "----------------------------[SETUP]\n"
     ;;;;;; DEBUG
     initialize-globals
     initialize-train
     initialize-exits
     initialize-passengers
   ; initialize-fire
     reset-ticks
     
end


to initialize-globals
   
   set exit1           patch 64 -13
   set exit2           patch 13 -54
   set exits-list    ( list exit1 exit2 )
   
end


to initialize-train
   import-pcolors "C:/Users/palli/OneDrive/Desktop/Modello_base/images/ambiente.png"
   ask patches [
     if pcolor = 86.6 [set pcolor cyan]
     if pcolor =  0   [set pcolor black]
     if pcolor = 64.3 [set pcolor green]
     if pcolor =  9.9 [set pcolor white]
       
     set fire? false
     set accessible? false ; Imposta tutte le patch come inaccessibili di default
   ]
   
   ask patches with [pcolor = white] [
     set accessible? true ; Contrassegna le patch verdi come accessibili
   ]
end


to initialize-exits
  set exit1 patch 64 -13
  set exit2 patch 13 -54
  set exits-list (list exit1 exit2)
end


to initialize-passengers
  create-passengers passenger-count [
    set shape "person business"
    set size 2
    set color yellow
    set in-seat? false  ; Cambia da true a false
    set safe? false
    set dead? false
    set panic? true
    set current-heading 0
    set my-exits-list [] ; SET here, it must assign a []-list to this property BEFORE next call to choose-exit
    set target-exit nobody ; SET this as the initial target-exit
    
    ; Aggiungi il seguente blocco di codice per posizionare casualmente i passeggeri in patch accessibili
    let target one-of patches with [accessible?]
    move-to target
    set target-exit choose-exit patch-here ; Aggiorna il target-exit dopo esserti spostato sulla patch iniziale
  ]
end



to-report choose-exit [current-position]  ;; still ignore the passed parameter-value

   let possible-exits        []
   let shortest-distance 10000
   let nearest-exit          nobody

   foreach exits-list [ exitUnderTest ->

           let exit-coords (list [pxcor] of exitUnderTest [pycor] of exitUnderTest) ;; Get exit coordinates as a list
           let exit-distance distance exitUnderTest

           if  exit-distance < shortest-distance [
               set shortest-distance exit-distance
               set nearest-exit      exitUnderTest
               set possible-exits    []
           ]

           if  exit-distance = shortest-distance [
              
               set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits ;; Use exit coordinates instead of the patch object
                      
           ]
   ]

   if length possible-exits = 0 [
       print "No exits found."
       report nobody
   ]

   let lucky-exit-coords    one-of     possible-exits
   let lucky-exit           patch-at ( item 0 lucky-exit-coords )
                                     ( item 1 lucky-exit-coords ) ;; Get the object using the coordinates
   set target-exit          lucky-exit
   
   
   set my-exits-list   lput lucky-exit my-exits-list
         
   report lucky-exit
end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; FUNZIONI GO ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to go
   ;;;;;; DEBUG
          type "----------------------------[GO.tick]\n"
   ;;;;;; DEBUG
     
   ask passengers [
       if panic? [
          let  target-to-exit choose-exit patch-here
          face target-to-exit
       ]
       move
   ]
   tick
end
;;;go()

to move
   
   if panic? [
      move-to target-exit
      if  patch-here = target-exit [
          set safe?    true
          set in-seat? false
      ]
   ]
end
;;;move()
```

I have solved the previous 2 problems, This problem occurred to me, the passengers move but do not go towards the exit in a smart way and remain in the centre moving around, they also move out of the edge of the room. How can I solve it?

Comment: Would you mind to actually post the whole, complete, reproducible MCVE code? Fractions of code neither represent the as-is problem, nor form a standard MCVE that Stack Overflow is working for decades on. Thank you for your kind reconsideration & update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The MCVE syntax needed a few touches, feel free to improve it further ( other components like `initialize-fire` remained still missing in the MCVE ) :

```
breed [  passengers    passenger]
breed [  fire-spots  a-fire-spot]
breed [ smoke-spots a-smoke-spot]

globals [        exit1            ;;   pID
                 exit2            ;;   pID
                 exits-list       ;; [ pID ... ]
                 passenger_count  ;;   integer
]

passengers-own [ in-seat?         ;; boolean
                 safe?            ;; boolean
                 dead?            ;; boolean
                 panic?           ;; boolean
                 current-heading  ;; turtleHDG
                 target-exit      ;;   pID
                 my-exits-list    ;; [ pID ... ]
                 item?            ;; boolean
]

patches-own [    accessible?      ;; boolean
                 fire?            ;; boolean
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; FUNZIONI SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to setup
   
   __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
     ;;;;;; DEBUG
            type "----------------------------[SETUP]\n"
     ;;;;;; DEBUG
     initialize-globals
     initialize-train
     initialize-exits
     initialize-passengers
   ; initialize-fire
     reset-ticks
     
end


to initialize-globals
   
   set exit1           patch 64 -13
   set exit2           patch 13 -54
   set exits-list    ( list exit1 exit2 )
   set passenger_count 2
end


to initialize-train
   
 ; import-pcolors "C:/Users/palli/OneDrive/Desktop/Modello_base/images/ambiente.png"
   ask patches [
       if pcolor = 86.6 [set pcolor cyan]
       if pcolor =  0   [set pcolor black]
       if pcolor = 64.3 [set pcolor green]
       if pcolor =  9.9 [set pcolor white]
       
       set fire? false
   ]
   ask patches [
       set accessible? false
   ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor >   5 and
                      pxcor <  64 and
                      pycor >  -5 and
                      pycor < -54 ] [
       set accessible? true
   ]
end
;;;initialise-train()

to initialize-exits
   
   set exit1        patch 64 -13
   set exit2        patch 13 -54
   set exits-list ( list exit1 exit2 )
end
;;;initialize-exits()

to initialize-passengers
   
   create-passengers passenger_count [
        ; set shape          "person business"
          set size            2
          set color           yellow
          set in-seat?        true
          set safe?           false
          set dead?           false
          set panic?          false
          set current-heading 0
          set my-exits-list   []                     ; SET here as SET target-exit calls choose-exit()-method, where this attribute must have been already assigned a list-value
          set target-exit     choose-exit patch-here ; SET this as the initial target-exit
  ]
  ask passengers [
      let     target one-of patches with [accessible?]
    ; HANDLE a case resulting in an empty agentSet { patches with ... }
      ;;;;;;; DEBUG                     face target
              type word who "-will TRY: face target\n"
              type word "AFTER:" word patches with [accessible?] "IN patches with [accessible?]\n"
              type word "WITH:" word target  "IN target\n"
      face    target
              type "EXEC'd...PASS\n\n"
      ;;;;;; DEBUG ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
      move-to target
  ]
end
;;;initialize-passengers()

to-report choose-exit [current-position]  ;; you still ignore the passed parameter-value

   let possible-exits        []
   let shortest-distance 10000
   let nearest-exit          nobody

   foreach exits-list [ exitUnderTest ->

           let exit-coords (list [pxcor] of exitUnderTest [pycor] of exitUnderTest) ;; Get exit coordinates as a list
           let exit-distance distance exitUnderTest

           if  exit-distance < shortest-distance [
               set shortest-distance exit-distance
               set nearest-exit      exitUnderTest
               set possible-exits    []
           ]

           if  exit-distance = shortest-distance [
               ;;;;;; DEBUG                     set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits
                      type word who "-will TRY: set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits\n"
                      type word "WITH:" word exit-coords          "IN exit-coords\n"
                      type word "WITH:" word possible-exits       "IN possible-exits\n"
               set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits ;; Use exit coordinates instead of the patch object
                      type "EXEC'd...PASS\n\n"
               ;;;;;; DEBUG ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
           ]
   ]

   if length possible-exits = 0 [
       print "No exits found."
       report nobody
   ]

   let lucky-exit-coords    one-of     possible-exits
   let lucky-exit           patch-at ( item 0 lucky-exit-coords )
                                     ( item 1 lucky-exit-coords ) ;; Get the object using the coordinates
   set target-exit          lucky-exit
   
   ;;;;;; DEBUG                     set my-exits-list lput lucky-exit my-exits-list
          type word who "-will TRY: set my-exits-list lput lucky-exit my-exits-list\n"
          type word "WITH:" word lucky-exit     "IN lucky-exit\n"
          type word "WITH:" word my-exits-list  "IN my-exits-list\n"
   set my-exits-list   lput lucky-exit my-exits-list
          type "EXEC'd...PASS\n\n"
   ;;;;;; DEBUG ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
   report lucky-exit
end
;;;report choose-exit()

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; FUNZIONI GO ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to go
   ;;;;;; DEBUG
          type "----------------------------[GO.tick]\n"
   ;;;;;; DEBUG
     
   ask passengers [
       if panic? [
          let  target-to-exit choose-exit patch-here
          face target-to-exit
       ]
       move
   ]
   tick
end
;;;go()

to move
   
   if panic? [
      move-to target-exit
      if  patch-here = target-exit [
          set safe?    true
          set in-seat? false
      ]
   ]
end
;;;move()
```

This works with respect to failing to meet the `lput`-syntax with a `list`-*instance* ( the call `to-initialize-passengers` asked a not-yet assigned `passenger`-*property `[my-exits-list]`*, which was until its later 1st assignment pre-initialised with a system default integer value of `0` )

Q/A-**PASS**-ed

A next problem is straightforward in the debug-report :
Q/A-**FAIL**-s

```
----------------------------[SETUP]
0-will TRY: set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits
WITH:         [-2 -13] IN exit-coords
WITH:               [] IN possible-exits
EXEC'd...PASS

0-will TRY: set my-exits-list lput lucky-exit my-exits-list
WITH:   (patch -2 -13) IN lucky-exit
WITH:               [] IN my-exits-list
EXEC'd...PASS

1-will TRY: set possible-exits lput exit-coords possible-exits
WITH:         [-2 -13] IN exit-coords
WITH:               [] IN possible-exits
EXEC'd...PASS

1-will TRY: set my-exits-list lput lucky-exit my-exits-list
WITH:   (patch -2 -13) IN lucky-exit
WITH:               [] IN my-exits-list
EXEC'd...PASS

1-will TRY: face target
AFTER:   (agentset, 0 patches) IN patches with [accessible?]
WITH:                   nobody IN target
```

A good, robust code has to assume corner-cases, where empty-`[]`-*instances* might crash an otherwise reasonably meant code.

Go solve these cases, with delivering some emergency-case value for those cases, where a `[]`-*instance* resulted in being empty.

> As per comment below - MCVE-code, without having the variable `passenger-count` defined (was perhaps "injected" from a GUI-interface design, likely via a field or a slider) at least as a mock-up fix, was not complete ( if you have added some other code-sections later, not published in the MCVE above, there you go and now have to remove the mock-up fix or solve the new errors introduced by/with the new code-section added as appropriate ) :

[image]

> *"People are not born in the environment I created but in the top left-hand corner and do not move. Why?"*

Because the `create-passengers passenger_count [...]`-*code* does not specify any particular randomisation of the `passenger`-*instances* initial locations. Code it there and you can have whatever behaviour upon "birth" w.r.t. environment ( as per loaded picture ?)

Why the `passengers` do not move? Check your code and contents of variables, if you want other than the so far coded behaviour. The current code has a `global` named `panic?` which was pre-assigned a `false`, i.e. the `if panic? [...]`-*clause* will never execute the commands there, unless something somewhere at some unknown time switch the boolean `panic?` into a `true`-*state*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but with your code this error appear: there is already a global variable called passenger-count

Comment: Not in my IDE. The global was added as it was not defined otherwise in the MCVE and threw a "*Nothing named PASSENGER-COUNT has been defined.*" error otherwise. In case you added some further code-sections to the revised MCVE-code, search in those sections and/or remove the mock-up `passenger-count` fixing definition from the `globals [ ... passenger-count ]`

Comment: I have put passenger-count  as comment like you and when press setup button this error appear: `LPUT expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead.
error while passenger 1 running LPUT
  called by procedure CHOOSE-EXIT
  called by procedure INITIALIZE-PASSENGERS
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'` How can i fix? Edited code

Comment: Creeps side-ways. MCVE-code requires to have `globals [ ... passenger-count ]` as otherwise it would by syntactically wrong ( having an undefined variable ). Similarly the `choose-exit [ current-position ]`-*reporter* did not use a value, passed from caller via the `current-position` parameter at all, yet still works as needed in computing a  `distance exitUnderTest` for each respective `passenger`-*agent* instance in the population. Last comment claimed an error in `lput aValue aList` yet in both of the MCVE-code appearances of `lput`-*reporter* list-parts are proper `list`-instances, not `0`

Comment: How can i fix my code to make it work?

Comment: Start with cross-checking, where did you define `passenger-count`-*value* once you has changed the corrected code above by commenting out the `globals [ ... passenger-count ]`-*missing-definition-fix*. Similarly next find, what has caused, in your modified code, the `list`-*parameter* inside either of the present `lput <aValue> <aList>`-*reporter* clauses, as the above provided code was error-free in this ( as in either of the two cases a proper `list`-*instance* was delivered to the said `lput`-*reporter* clauses. Go through your modified code and trace the root source of the new problems

Comment: I took the code from your answer I did not change anything, all the code is what I put in the question. That's why I don't understand what could be wrong

Comment: My localhost IDE NetLogo 6.2.2 shows no error for corrected MCVE-code. WebBased NetLogo has also no errors ( except an obvious and trivial one -- (Line 28) Nothing named __CLEAR-ALL-AND-RESET-TICKS has been defined. )
While one cannot test my localhost IDE, anyone can test the other IDE - WebBased NetLogo and copy/paste the source-code ( and compile it error-free as a proof ) at https://www.netlogoweb.org/launch#https://www.netlogoweb.org/assets/modelslib/Sample%20Models/Networks/Preferential%20Attachment.nlogo